# Why MYSQL FullText search Match AGAINST doesn't work properly?

Tags: mysql, sql

I got a very simple Table with 2 rows:

```
 create table T1(text varchar(50), FULLTEXT KEY `text` (`text`)
               ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
 insert into T1 (text) values ('local unit shipping fee 12');
 insert into T1 (text) values ('local unit insernational fee 21');
```

Ok, now i run:

1- `Select * from T1 where MATCH(text) AGAINST ('local');` no result

2- `Select * from T1 where MATCH(text) AGAINST ('fee');` no result

3- `Select * from T1 where MATCH(text) AGAINST ('+fee' In Boolean mode);` no result

4- `Select * from T1 where MATCH(text) AGAINST ('+shipping' In Boolean mode);` 1 row comes out

5- `Select * from T1 where MATCH(text) AGAINST ('+unit' In Boolean mode);` 2 rows come out.

You can see sqlfiddle here
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9a0866/13

Please explain this to me clearly how MYSQL fulltext search work, why it shows nothing for such a very simple logic query?

I am confused!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your corpora is so small that in natural language mode the 'local' and 'fee' words are treated as stopwords and ignored - they match everywhere.

This happens because as a default heuristic you wouldn't want a query to return every row, or every other row of a 100GB dataset.

The default matching threshold is 0.5, and to obviate it in your specific example you will need to add more rows:

```
create table T1(text varchar(50), FULLTEXT KEY `text` (`text`)
 ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

insert into T1 (text) values ('local unit shipping fee 12');
insert into T1 (text) values ('a row');
insert into T1 (text) values ('another row');
insert into T1 (text) values ('and another row');
insert into T1 (text) values ('local unit international fee 21');

select * from T1 where MATCH(text) AGAINST ('local');

Output:
TEXT
local unit shipping fee 12
local unit international fee 21
```

When you add more rows without the word 'local' the query will score below the threshold and you will see the relevant rows returned. Also note that the word 'fee' is too short for a natural language query. It needs to be at least 4 characters in length.

The boolean full-text searches do not have a threshold.

Comment: really, my real DB has 200 000 row & 'local unit shipping fee 12' is one of those rows? why so small?

Comment: also it doesn't make any sense cos the QUery should work in any size , no matter how small the table it should show the right results

Comment: i added 2 more rows but still there is no result
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/181c3/1

Comment: @Tum two more rows = threshold of 0.5 (2 matching rows, 2 not matching), you will not get a result. As I mentioned add **three more rows** to surpass the threshold.

Comment: here, I added a lot of rows but it still doesn't work
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/51564/1

Comment: In all the rows you added - the word 'local' appears. The query is going to match more than half of the rows, and nothing will be returned.

Comment: so how google search work, they don't include local?

Comment: I don't really see how your question relates to google search - you asked about why your example doesn't work. Google are not using MySQL as a back-end and they are of course not using MySQL version of natural language queries.